# Threshold for and Variations of Exact logistic regression

Tags: logistic, markov-chain-montecarlo, small-sample, multinomial-logit, exact-test

According to [this UCLA tutorial](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/exlogit.htm) **exact logistic regression** (`elrm::elrm` in R) should be prefered to the **logistic regression** `glm(... ,family = binomial)`in R if

- the sample size is small AND/OR
- Some cells are empty

My questions:

1. What does small sample mean in this case (e.g. n<30 or n < 300 or n<3 000)
2. If **exact logistic regression** performs better than **logistic regression** in some cases why don't we always use **exact logistic regression**? I know that exact logistic regression is often more computationally expensive because of the Monte Carlo Markov Chain Algorithm. Is this the only reason?
3. Are there also **multinomial/ordered and probit versions** of the **exact logistic regression**?